# Jquery - apply method to all elements returned

Tags: jquery, html

this is probably pretty straightforward but i'm struggling with it - I want to pause all videos I have running in a div container. At the moment, this is what I have:

```
// Doesn't work
$("#vid").find("video").get().pause();
// Works
$("#vid").find("video").get(0).pause();
```

What's the best way to apply the pause function to each video element? A for/each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('video','#vid').each(function(){
     this.pause(); //find all videos in #vid and pause them
});
```

Comment: You could also write the css selector as `$('#vid video')`

Comment: @ChrisG. -- I could but where is the fun in that?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#vid').find('video').each(function(){
     $(this).pause();
});
```

Comment: That does a `pause` function on a jQuery object with **does not** have a `pause` function